# Why SED delete first character after replacement pattern

Tags: bash, sed

I was wondering what is wrong with:

`b="inst.;inst" ; echo $b | sed -e 's/\.;[^ ]/\n /'
inst
 nst`

**Expected Output**

```
inst
inst
```

Thank too much in advance for any clue.

Comment: why the `[^ ]` in this case (sample) ? this is certainly part of a more complexe case where some space (or other) could occur.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your pattern matches three characters. A period, a semi-colon, and some non-space character. You then replace all three of those characters with two characters (newline and space).

So your pattern matches `.;i` and you replace that with `\n`.

You need to capture and re-insert that non-space character.

Use `\([^ ]\)` in the pattern and `\n \1` as the replacement.

Answer (score 2):

You are replacing the first character of inst, capture and preserve it instead, i.e.

```
sed -e 's/\.;\([^ ]\)/\n \1/'
```

Comment: Thank too much, +1 but not chose because it wasn't explained as Etan did.

Answer (score 0):

Or just change your command to b="inst.;inst" ; echo $b | sed -e 's/.;/\n/'
replace .; with a newline

Comment: This only works if there aren't any `; ` entries he doesn't want replaced.